# Organização e manutenção do Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou começando com o uso do Bootstrap com MVC 4 e durante o planejamento notei que a tela principal do sistema terá muitas divs. Muitas delas podem se repetir (exatamente iguais) em outras telas.

Para facilitar a manutenção futura e organização do código eu estava pensando em separar algumas divs em arquivos html, ou seja, minha tela principal teria cerca de 4 includes de outros html, o que geram 4 requisições adicionais por visita. Não sei se é preocupante.

Alguém tem alguma(s) dica(s) com o objetivo de melhorar a organização do código e manutenção futura?

Comment: Acredito que se você postar seu código ajudará...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você chama de "Include", o nome em ASP.NET MVC é **Partial**. *Partials* são fragmentos de código (extensão .cshtml, igual às das *Views*), e que a nomenclatura normalmente é normatizada com um "_" (underline) na frente do nome.

A separação não apenas é boa como é encorajada. Não precisa se preocupar com performance: como as *Views* são compiladas dinamicamente, o desempenho de uma *View* com ou sem *Partials* é o mesmo.

As dicas são basicamente explicações de funcionalidades:

- Uma *Partial* dentro de um diretório `Shared` é visível a todas as outras *Views*;
- Uma *Partial* dentro de um diretório de *Views* normalmente é visível somente àquelas *Views*, mas pode ser chamada com a devida especificação de diretórios;

  Exemplo, suponha que estou renderizando `~/Views/Produtos/Detalhes.cshtml` e quero exibir mais informações sobre a categoria do produto:

  ```
  @Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/CategoriasDeProdutos/_Detalhes.cshtml", produto);
  ```
- *Partials* dentro de *Partials* é uma boa prática;
- *Partials* não devem (nem podem) ter código JavaScript dentro. O código deve ficar na *View* pai, para evitar comportamentos estranhos.
- Há duas maneiras de chamar *Partials*:

  ```
  @Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/CategoriasDeProdutos/_Detalhes.cshtml", produto);
  ```

  `RenderPartial` retorna `void` e escreve direto na saída da requisição.

  ```
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/CategoriasDeProdutos/_Detalhes.cshtml", produto);
  ```

  `Partial` retorna uma `String` com o HTML da *Partial*. Pode ser atribuída a uma variável.

[Há um artigo bem completo no CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC) que explica isso em mais detalhes.

Comment: Salve Cigano. Gostei da resposta. E com relação ao javascript? Existem funções que são comuns em todo o sistema (validarEmail por exemplo) e outras que são específicos de uma determinada página ($("#divModal").dialog({...})), você aconselharia colocar tudo em um único .js, separado ou deixa no código da própria página?
Vlw.

Comment: @Onaiggac Recomendo você colocar o código dentro de um JS (diretório `Scripts`) e chamá-lo dentro de `@section scripts` de cada `View` pai (que chama a Partial em questão). Aproveite e use o recurso de *Bundling* para minificar o código em produção.

Comment: Encontrei um artigo interessante para estes casos que me pareceu ser bom.
http://wildermuth.com/2012/01/20/Modern_Web_Development_-_Part_2