# Partial não é renderizada

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

De acordo [este link de outra pergunta minha que acabou gerando erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38214/normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-tabelas-e-relacionamentos) onde segui os passos referentes a uma outra pergunta, está me acontecendo um erro um tanto, estranho.

Criei uma *partial* para fazer as manipulações na tabela de Telefones do meu projeto. Só que simplesmente ela não é renderizada de forma alguma... Ela deveria aparecer nas *views* de *create* e *edit* dos dados do aluno.

Vou colocar os códigos que usei:

## *View* *Create*( e a de *edit*, que é a mesma coisa)

```
@model SisGAL.Models.Aluno

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Aluno</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoEnsino, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TipoEnsino, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoEnsino, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomePai, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomePai, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomePai, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomeMae, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeMae, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomeMae, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomeResponsavel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeResponsavel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomeResponsavel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @if (Model != null && Model.Telefones != null)
        {
            foreach (var telefone in Model.Telefones)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_PartialTelefone", telefone);
            }
        }
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnoLetivo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnoLetivo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnoLetivo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ano, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ano, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ano, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Turma, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Turma, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Turma, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumeroChamada, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumeroChamada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroChamada, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Foto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Foto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Foto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Observacoes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Observacoes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Observacoes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

## *Partial* dos telefones

```
@model SisGAL.Models.Telefone

@{
Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Telefones"))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AlunoId)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Numero)
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.TipoTelefone)
}
```

Obs: Estou usando o pacote BeginCollectionItem.

Comment: Você inseriu pelo menos um telefone vazio no aluno pelo *Controller*?

Comment: Não deu pra inserir pelo _controller_ por que não é renderizada a _div_. Eu inseri direto na mão, lá na tabela do banco e referenciei o _id_ do aluno. E mesmo assim nada...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não use `RenderPartial` para este caso:

```
Html.RenderPartial("_PartialTelefone", telefone);
```

Use apenas `Partial` e com o `@` na frente:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialTelefone", telefone);
```

[Aqui explico o porquê](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28929/organiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-manuten%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-bootstrap/28931#28931).

Comment: Mesmo assim não deu. Não apareceu nada !

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Você chegou a colocar um breakpoint aqui pra ver o que acontece? `@if (Model != null && Model.Telefones != null)`. Desconfio que nem chega ao código de renderização da Partial.

Comment: Olha não coloquei. Mas tenho certeza que não chega, porque a partial não aparece de forma alguma. E se tento acessa ela via URL, da que não existe aquela página

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Sim, porque é uma Partial. Ela não é acessível via URL. Está no link que coloquei na resposta. Refaça o teste com o breakpoint, por favor.

Comment: Essa _partial_ deve estar dentro da pasta de _views_ do aluno certo ? Refiz, e não apareceu nada.

Comment: Gera isso: 'Model != null && Model.Telefones != null | false'. Ou seja, _null_... Que loucura.

Comment: Acho que é o caso de você inspecionar o Model e os atributos dele.

Comment: O model telefone ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago O Model de Aluno.

Comment: Mas eu fiz igual você colocou lá na outra pergunta. O que pode estar errado ?

Comment: Não sei. Acho que falta Debug nisso aí.

Comment: Entendi. Vou ver o que posso fazer aqui