# Dois models e um controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, banco-de-dados

Seguindo o raciocínio [dessa minha outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38214/normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-tabelas-e-relacionamentos), onde crio dois *models* para manipulações, como que eu poderia usar um *controller* para fazer as manipulações nas tabelas ?

Meu intuito em fazer isso é que na mesma *view* eu consiga fazer cadastro das duas informações de uma vez só.  Pois eu não queria criar um *controller* pra fazer as modificações na tabela de telefones e sim no *controller* de aluno.

Isso é viável? Se não, eu poderia usar AJAX e se possível, exemplos?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39055/partial-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-renderizada/39056#39056

Comment: Quer que eu coloque essa ai também @CiganoMorrisonMendez ?

Comment: Não precisa. O link já está ali à direita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...eu poderia usar um controller para fazer as manipulações nas tabelas ?

Na verdade o controller não manipula tabelas.

Comentando bem a grosso modo, o controller recebe as requisições do usuário GET/POST, mapea para *Action* e retorna uma *View*. Não tem nenhuma responsabilidade de manipular tabelas, **isso seria uma responsabilidade do seu Model**.

Então, você pode por exemplo:

1- Criar uma classe chamada AlunoViewModel, que vai ser uma espécie de *container* de todas as informações desejadas para cadastro do aluno (por exemplo: nome, telefone, endereco, etc). Essa classe inclusive pode ter um método para salvar o aluno.

```
public class AlunoViewModel
{    
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Endereço")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Telefone")]
    public string NumeroTelefone { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Telefone> Telefones {get;set;}

    // Demais propriedades

    // Método para salvar um aluno
    public static void Salvar(AlunoViewModel alunoViewModel)
    {
        //Seu código para salvar uma aluno
    }
}
```

2- Criar um controller e inserir *Actions* (uma para exibir a tela de cadastro "GET", outra para receber os dados informados "POST")

```
public class AlunoController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Criar()
    {                    
       return View(new AlunoViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Criar(AlunoViewModel alunoViewModel)
    {           
        //Agora usando as informações de alunoViewModel você chama o seu Model para criar os objetos (aluno, telefone, etc) e salvar no banco.
        AlunoViewModel.Salvar(alunoViewModel);
    }
}
```

3- Criar a View do tipo AlunoViewModel para ser exibida no cadastro.

```
@model Models.AlunoViewModel    
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cadastro de Aluno";        
}

 @*

   Aqui vai o código em razor para exibir as informações do cadastro

*@
```

Sim, é viável cadastrar as informações de telefone, pais, etc do aluno seja **usando ou não AJAX.**

No caso do cadastro dos telefones do aluno, você pode ter uma propriedade **NumeroTelefone** (controle do tipo textbox por exemplo) e um botão para o usuário adicionar o telefone na lista (controle do tipo ListBox por exemplo). Assim que o usuário digitar o número, clicar no botão, você adiciona o telefone informado no ListBox (relacionado a propriedade Telefones). No post da tela de cadastro você receberá essa lista de telefones e associa ao aluno para salvar.

Comment: no _controller_ ali e na _viewmodel_, os métodos 'Salvar' e 'Criar', eu poderia usar o código criado por _scaffolding_ nas _actions_ ? Poderia colocar um exemplo de código de como fazer essa inserção usando lista ?