# Como retornar várias valores de uma classe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Segue código:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult teste1(int num1, int num2)
{
  // Aqui quero obter os valores da variável model1 e model2  da classe MyClass
  var result = MyClass.Teste2(num1 , num2);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static Teste2(int num1, int num2)
  {
     var model1 = new AspNetUser();
     var model2 = new AspNetUser1();

     using (var ctx = new Entities())
     { 
        model1 = ctx.Table.Where( x => ...).FirstOrDefault();
        model2 = ctx.Table.Where( x => ...).FirstOrDefault();
     }

     //aqui: como retornar com "model1" e "model2" para ação "ActionResult" onde tem variável "result"?
  }    
}
```

Como posso retornar com variáveis `model1` e `model2` para variável `result` ? Porque o `AspNetUser` e `AspNetUser` tbm são classes criado com ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Já tentei fazer um `ToArray` ou `ToList` e não consegui. Estou tendo dificuldade de retornar.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Esses códigos não fazem muito sentido. Seria melhor você colocar um exemplo real que tem dúvida. Se quer saber apenas como retornar mais de um valor já existe resposta para isto em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101 e portanto é duplicata. Ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94882/101 se não está usando C# 7. A solução exata depende do que precisa.

Comment: Um outro exemplo que talvez não seja exatamente igual mais pode ser útil [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80993/30045](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80993/30045)

Comment: O comentário não ajudou muito, mas parece confirmar que o que eu já achava. Só não posso dizer se é melhor solução porque não tem informações suficientes para tomar essa decisão. Ou deve usar tuplas ou uma classe como o Brunno indicou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira correta é definindo um *ViewModel*:

```
public class UsuariosViewModel
{
    public AspNetUser Model1 { get; set; }        
    public AspNetUser1 Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

Ou seja, você pode fazer um *Helper* assim (*Model* é outra coisa):

```
public static class MyClass
{
  public static UsuariosViewModel Teste2(int num1, int num2)
  {    
     using (var ctx = new Entities())
     { 
        return new UsuariosViewModel
        {
            Model1 = ctx.Table.FirstOrDefault(x => ...),
            Model2 = ctx.Table.FirstOrDefault(x => ...)
        };
     }
  }    
}
```

E o retorno para a *View*:

```
public ActionResult teste1(int num1, int num2)
{
  // Aqui quero obter os valores da variável model1 e model2  da classe MyClass
  var result = MyClass.Teste2(num1 , num2);
  return View(result); // result será UsuariosViewModel.
}
```

Comment: Cigano, pra que serve helper ?

Comment: Em ASP.NET MVC, um *Helper* é uma classe estática responsável por ter uma lógica que é usada várias vezes no decorrer da aplicação. Por exemplo, uma pesquisa ao site dos Correios pode ser implementada em um *Helper*. Posso responder isso com mais detalhes em uma pergunta sobre *Helpers* em ASP.NET MVC, se desejar.

Comment: Só abrir outra pergunta e colar o link aqui pra mim, para que eu seja notificado.