# Como carregar uma partialview por uma requisicao AJAX?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Nao consigo carregar uma partialview em uma div !

```
     <fieldset>
<legend>Contato:</legend>
@Html.Label("Tipo Contato: ")
@Html.DropDownListFor(t => t.CodTipoContato, Model.TipoContatoList, new { id = "tipoContato", name = "tipoContato", onchange = "CarregarPartialView()" })
```

```
      <div id="result">
   @if(Model!=null)
   {        
        if (Model.CodTipoContato == 10)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_ContatoEmailFields");

        }
        else if(Model.CodTipoContato==0)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_EmptyView");

        }

        else
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_ContatoTelefoneFields");
        }
   }
```

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function CarregarPartialView(CodTipoContato){        
       var codTipoContato = $("#tipoContato").val();            
        $.ajax(
        {
        type: "GET",
        url: "TipoContato",
        data: "CodTipoContato="+codTipoContato,           
        sucess: function (result) { $('#resultado').html(result)}
         });
        };
     </script>

    public PartialViewResult TipoContato(int CodTipoContato)
    {
        var tcList = ConsultaRepositorio.ObterTipoContato();
        var codTipoContato = CodTipoContato;
        var tipoContatoVM = new SuperViewModel()
        {
            TipoContatoList = Extentions.ObterTipoContatosList(tcList),
            CodTipoContato=codTipoContato
        };
        return PartialView("_ContatoFields",tipoContatoVM);
    }
```

Comment: O que acontece? Algum erro?

Comment: a partialview nao é carregada dentro da div!

Comment: No callback da sua chamada ajax você está usando `$('#resultado').html(result)` mas no HTML sua `div` tem o id `result`. Será que o problema não é isso?

Comment: não é isso não ,corrigi e continuo sem que carregue a partialview dentro da div! nao carrega nada!

Comment: O que aparece na aba `Network` nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador (assumindo que você esteja usando Firefox ou Chrome)?

Comment: pow aparece a minha partialview selecionada!! mas pq nao carrega dentro da pagina??

Comment: Você tem que olhar na aba `Network`(ou Rede) e ver o que a requisição ajax retorna.

Answer (score 0):

Pro seu caso, não use assim:

```
Html.RenderPartial("_ContatoEmailFields");
```

Use assim:

```
Html.Partial("_ContatoEmailFields");
```

[Explico isso nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28929/organiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-manuten%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-bootstrap/28931#28931).